# How to create a conference scenario without being owner of the avenue through the API?

Tags: foursquare

Is there a way to use FourSquare in a conference scenario without being the owner of the venue?

I'm looking for a way to create for multiple conferences in multiple geographic locations various checkins based on our conference schedule with custom badges, rewards and specials.

Is this possible via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, for a few reasons:

1. An `event` is an aspect of a `venue` in Foursquare, so under that model only the venue owner has control over the events at the venue.
2. In addition, Foursquare currently supports music and movie events only, and doesn't actually let venue owners create events at venues via the API. See here for more details: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events
3. Only the owner of a venue can add rewards and specials. These benefits are associated with venues as opposed to events.
4. Only brands can create custom badges, and this cannot be done via the API (there's a manual approval process involved): http://business.foursquare.com/brands/

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but very glad to have some more clarity.  Thanks!